# Examples of interpreters embedded in iPhone Applications?

Tags: iphone, runtime, interpreter

I'm trying to find examples of interpreted languages ported to the iPhone, with source code available to show how to embed it, without Jailbreaking the device:

I've found:

- Ruby: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1163
- Lua: http://www.mobileorchard.com/announcing-iphone-wax-native-uikit-iphone-apps-written-in-lua/

and I'd like to see what else is out there. I know that Apple may or may not allow usage of an interpreter in an app (or downloading new code to run in the interpeter), but I'm ok with that, as I want this mostly to simplify development.

Are there any other examples out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Nu](http://floatopian.com/~reddaly/nu-iphone.html).

Nu is a Lisp-on-ObjC-runtime thing.  The link above is to information on iPhone embedding.  The language homepage is [here](http://programming.nu/).

Answer (score 1):

[PHP](http://www.hackint0sh.org/f126/7299.htm), [Python](http://www.saurik.com/id/5), [Tcl](http://www.installerapps.com/2007/11/08/tcl/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You made me realize though that I wasn't as specific in my question as I should've been, being that I'm looking for examples that don't require jailbreaking, and preferably have some example source to show how to embed the interpreter in an app! I've added some clarifying points to my question to help with this... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[iPhone Frotz](http://code.google.com/p/iphonefrotz/) is an interpreter for the Z-Machine and is open source.

Answer (score 1):

How about [C#](http://monotouch.net/)?

And soon also [Flash](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/#examples)..

Comment: These are specifically not capable of doing interpretation.  They get compiled ahead of time.

The poster seems to be after something that is more an extension of the IDE than of the program.  This is how I use F-Script (on the mac), and it is very useful this way.

Comment: Actually, I agree that C# and Flash aren't what I want, but F-Script isn't it either. I do want an interpreter embedded in the app, so scripts could be run on it from the users documents directory. I know apple won't allow me to download new code to run in the interpreter, but for development, quick prototyping, and allowing other devs to code against an engine I've built, an embedded interpreter works great.

Comment: I use F-Script embedded in the app as a dev tool.  Take a look at F-Script Anywhere.

Or, for a quick demo jump to the 30 minute mark in this tech talk: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-2563969716754696790

Answer (score 0):

The Processing environment has been adapted for the iPhone. I believe that it comes from ProcessingJs which translates the Processing code to Javascript.

Processing for IOS (if the link doesn't work, search for it)
http://itunes.apple.com/sg/artist/boyd-rotgans/id492576046

or a commercial version that allows you to import/export scripts
http://itunes.apple.com/app/pr0c0d1n6/id493549542?mt=8

There is also a tool to convert ProcessingJs scripts to native iPhone Apps.
http://luckybite.com/iprocessing/